# Binomial And Multinomial Classification in ML

Tags: data-science

I got a project in which my task is to build network  intrusion detection system to detect anomolies and attacks in the network.
There are two problems. 
1.  Binomial Classification: Activity is normal or attack
2.  Multinomial classification: Activity is normal or DOS or PROBE or R2L or U2R

But before this I get some confusion in these terms Binomial/Multinomial Classification.
Help me to understand/ if possible please share a sort code... which gives me more help.

I tried to search these term on google/youtube but can't find proper definition with some code

```
I do only these thing with my code:-
 clean/transform/outlier detect/missing value treatment
 model_selection/accuracy test
```

so my next step is to make classification of Binomial/Multinomial Classification
Thanks for help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do not hesitate to post on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ for these kind of question that is more Data Science than coding issue.

Second, the answer is as simple as :

- Binary (and **not** Binomial) Classification means **only 2 targets** to find.

  => In your case Normal vs Attack
- Multilabel / Multiclass / Multinomial Classification means **more than 2 targets** to find.

  => Your case : Normal, DOS, PROBE, REL & E2R.

You can find example on https://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning